# how to use inkwell so that the text can be easily tapped

Tags: flutter

Please see screenshot. Basically they are two containers in a row. Since the text in left is so long and wrapped that the whole left-side container is tappable, with its height greater than that of the right side. As a result, on the right side, only the area of text height is tappable. But I would like to make the whole height of right-side container tappable.

```dart
child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    parent._onSelectedChanged(index);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      item.content,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    parent._onSelectedChanged(index);
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                    child: Text(
                      item.rowid,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you please add some code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use two expanded widgets in the Row like this:

```
return Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('Left Container');
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print('Right Container');
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

I hope this helped you!

Comment: Already used expanded for a row, but I was referring to expanding text vertically so it can be easily tapped

Comment: So you want to increase the size of the text or how should I understand this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using IntrinsicHeight to wrap the row.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

there is a property in row and column

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
```

try placing this property in the row,and try it.

Comment: Thanks, have tried but the tappable area remained the same. I used IntrinsicHeight to solve it, but it is said IntrinsicHeight  is expensive.

Comment: Then try warping Expanded widget with Inkwell